# Power apps - SharePoint list lookup columns

Tags: lookup-column, powerapp

Is there any performance issues if we use the SharePoint list lookup columns in power apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real performance impact (values will be pulled as part of a single query using expand behind the scenes). There is a small impact in getting choices for an edit/new form but it's unlikely to be noticeable.

The biggest issue in using lookups in Power Apps is that the lookup column limit still applies. This limitation means that a view (or query) cannot contain more than 12 lookup columns (but this includes people columns including Created by and Modified by). So if you are planning on more than that in a single query you'll need to rethink your data structure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this limitation of 12 look up is for SharePoint list itself not the power app limitation. I mean yes you cannot define more than 12 lookups including people picker. And power app is dependent on SharePoint list in this scenario.  Drop downs / lookups always need extra work not in power app but in any framework. So in short saying power app performance in impacted is wrong I think.

Comment: If you use SharePoint as your data source in Power Apps its limitations become limitations in your app. I don't really understand the dismissiveness of your response. If you are looking for a different type of answer, I recommend updating your question to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question is simple does using SharePoint list lookups impact power app performance? If yes then how ?

Comment: Great, then I've already answer that. Read the first paragraph of my answer.